# Cntk can not detect my gpu by cntk.all_devices()

Tags: cntk

Cntk only detect 1 device(my cpu) by calling cntk.all_devices(). However I do have a gpu on my computer. By running the tutorial supported by cntk, I could get some info:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------------------
GPU info:

                Device[0]: cores = 48; computeCapability = 2.1; type = "NVS 310"; memory = 512 MB
-------------------------------------------------------------------

##############################################################################
#                                                                            #
# Train command (train action)                                               #
#                                                                            #
##############################################################################


Model has 9 nodes. Using CPU.
```

As an consequence, I can not use my gpu as by calling `set_default_device(gpu(0))`. How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minimum GPU compute capability for CNTK is [3.0](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/Setup-CNTK-on-Windows#checking-your-gpu-compatibility). (**Edit:** <strike>The fact that you can run the tutorial using cntk.exe indicates a bug somewhere in the v1 executable.</strike>). When you run the tutorial with cntk.exe, it prints out the GPU info, but still ends up using CPU: `Model has 9 nodes. Using CPU.`

The only way to solve this problem is to change the value of the constant [MininumCCMajorForGpu in BestGpu.cpp](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/master/Source/Common/BestGpu.cpp#L115) and recompile.

Comment: Thanks! But according to the [cuda tookit document](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#compute-capabilities), compute capability represents different feature support. If the source file was changed, will cntk work withour any errors?

Comment: You could certainly try and see if it works for you, but all bets are essentially off.